# Object caching - is it more efficient to store cloned objects or serialized data?

Tags: php, performance, serialization

Suppose I'm loading a large number of objects from a database. These are normal, plain PHP objects, no inheritance from anything fancy. Suppose I might change a few of these objects and want to write them back to the database, but only use the fields that actually differ in the UPDATE ... SET ... query. Also suppose that I don't know in advance which objects are going to be changed.

I'm thinking that I need to make a copy of all the objects loaded, and keep around for reference and comparison, should I need to write objects back to the database.

I see two possible approaches:

- I can either clone all the loaded objects and store in a separate list. When saving, look up the object in the list using an index, and compare the values.
- Or, I can simply serialize everything loaded into a string, and keep around. When saving, find the serialized object in the string (somehow), unserialize it, compare the values, and there you go.

In terms of efficiency (mostly memory, but speed is also a consideration), which would be favorable?

Comment: I'm not sure how many fields your objects have, but there's nothing wrong with updating all fields on the object regardless of whether only 1 or 2 have changed - this way you don't need to keep the original copy at all. Updating 20 fields will not be much slower than updating 2 fields, unless of course the table is huge and has indexes and other referencing tables.

Comment: @AleksG: 20 fields, 50 000 objects (a guessed large number) = 1 000 000 fields to update.

Comment: @hakre with that number of updates, OP would be better off disabling all indexes before any updates are made.

Comment: I'd say the number of object loaded vary in range from 100 - 10,000. The number of objects changed will typically be small (1-2%).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you actually needs something to compare if the state of the object has changed or not. If you even want to track not only which object has changed but also which member, you need to have a state per member.

As you don't want to extend the original objects (e.g. they could have a flag they invalidate when they are changed), you need to track the state from the outside. I'd say serializing is probably the best option then. Cloning will take more memory.

Comment: Tracking state makes sense. I could possibly inject some kind of "reasonably hidden field" into the objects that simply calculates a crc-32 of each field and stores away... I'm not sure if a crc-32 is foolproof enough though.

Comment: Hashes are not safe, especially CRC-32 is not. If you consider to modify the objects, each setter could set some state if the object is changed (modified), then it's easy and this will need the least memory.